# Python - Find First and Last white pixels coordinates

Tags: python, loops, numpy, image-processing, iteration

I need help in python coding a loop that goes through all the pixels in an image. I need to find all the white pixels and save the coordinates of the first detected pixel and the last. The image is a thresholded image (only white and black pixels). I did a nested loop but I don't know how to do the evaluation.

Comment: You probably don't need a loop, but could you show the type of array you're working with? For instance, a 5x5 array with random 'white' and 'black' pixels, in the same format as the real one you are working with? And your desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* do it with nested loops, if you wanted, but that will be slow and clunky. I'd recommend using the optimized methods built in to `numpy`

Assuming your image is a 2d `numpy` array with black values as `0` and white values at `255`, like this:

```
image = np.random.choice([0,255], size=(10,10), p=[0.8, 0.2])

>>> image
array([[  0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0, 255]])
```

You can find the first and last coordinates of white values (values equal to 255) like this:

```
white_pixels = np.array(np.where(image == 255))
first_white_pixel = white_pixels[:,0]
last_white_pixel = white_pixels[:,-1]
```

Resulting in this:

```
>>> first_white_pixel
array([0, 2])
>>> last_white_pixel
array([9, 9])
```

or, as a one liner:

```
first_white_pixel, last_white_pixel = np.array(np.where(image == 255))[:,[0,-1]].T
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is perfect, exactly what I needed and even better because is optimized.

Comment: Glad it helped!